# [SELENIUM]Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() cn anyone say how the constructor name is different from class name here

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I read in java basics while instantiating object we should use same class name as constructor with parameter firefox
which means webdriver driver= new webdriver(FirefoxDriver) then how come we are using 
Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()

kindly explain